# executable file compiled by MinGW x86_64-w64-mingw32 in Ubuntu not working on Windows

Tags: mingw, x86-64, cross-compiling, mxe

I am trying to create a executable file works on Windows 64bit from linux.

I am using [MXE](https://mxe.cc/) to cross compile c file on my ubuntu server.
And after I compile c file to .exe file, I move the file to my desktop(windows 10 64bit).

Here's what I did.

1. installed mingw-w64

   `sudo apt-get install mingw-w64`

   `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64`
2. I cloned the mxe git and set some attrs.

   `git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git`

   `cd mxe`

   `echo MXE_TARGETS=x86_64-w64-mingw32.static > settings.mk`

   `make cc`

   `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/mxe/usr/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
3. I created c file for test.

   ```
   cat<<'EOT' > test.c
   #include <stdio.h>
   void main()
   {
       printf("Hello World\n");
   }
   EOT
   ```
4. I compiled c file to exe file.

   `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test.exe test.c`

Finally I could get an exe file that I compiled by wingw, but when I try to open this file on my desktop Windows 10, it won't work.
There's only a short blink when I open this exe file.

I tried `x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-gcc` to compile the file, but won't work.

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-gcc: command not found
```

Comment: *There's only a short blink when I open this exe file.* Are you sure it's not just opening a terminal window, and then closing it again when the command exits after printing `\n`?  Some people write toy Windows programs with a dummy `getchar()` at the end, but the better solution is to set up something that keeps a terminal open after a command exits, or to run it from an existing terminal command-line shell.  (e.g. from `cmd` or powershell.)  Or maybe a batch script that does a `pause` after running a program.

Comment: Launch [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/) on your desktop and open `text.exe` in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get an error, it probably works.

You created a console application, so it will open a console window, print to it and when the program finishes the console window will close. That's the short blink you're seeing.

Open a Command Prompt or PowerShell window and run your `test.exe` from there. Type the full path to `test.exe`, or drag `test.exe` on the console window and press Enter. When the program exits, the console will remain open and you will see the output of your application.